# Grafana Variables Query using ElasticSearch - Filter doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am currently using Grafana v9.1.7 and ElasticSearch 8.4.2

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a dashboard that can filter the data by country. I have a keyword field named `honeypot_country` (it's a string that mapped into keyword in elastic). When this filter is selected, it should only provide set of data filtered by that country

[image]

[image]

I already tried to create a variable query to filter these data. But it doesn't filter as I want to. So, I hope anyone can help me with this issue. Thanks